# Running settimeout in the background

Tags: nativescript

Why doesn't settimeout/debounceTime work when the app is minimized? Events are still being triggered, but I was wondering if there is a way to make timers work while the app is backgrounded.

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/5423#issuecomment-366190657)... and for background activity [this](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/ios-runtime/how-to/BackgroundExecution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon user leaves your app, the system will stop it from running to reduce battery usage.

If you like your app to execute in background, you must use the appropriate options in the desired platform (Background Task / Fetch in iOS | Background services in Android).